# how can I save HTML content of HTML editor in c#

Tags: c#, html

I used this code to open the HTML page in HTML editor in c#.

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Multiselect = 
false, ValidateNames = true, Filter = "HTML|*.html" })


            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                webBrowser1.DocumentStream = fs;

            }
    }
```

and also I used this code to save the changes

```
 private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog svf = new SaveFileDialog();
        svf.Filter = "Text Files (.html)|*.html";

        if (svf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(svf.FileName);

            sw.WriteLine(webBrowser1);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

However, the only line is saved in my HTML page is this message: System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.
Do you have any idea that how can I save the content of the HTML page? Thanks

Comment: This line `sw.WriteLine(webBrowser1)` is implicitly calling `webBrowser1`'s `ToString()` method which gives you the content you're currently getting. You have to write `webBrowser1`'s documentStream.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work as you require:

`System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(svf.FileName);
 webBrowser1.DocumentStream.CopyTo(sw.BaseStream);
 sw.Flush();
 sw.Close();`

The reason yours does not work is because you're trying to write an object to a stream directly, which as stated implicitly calls the ToString() method.

Comment: CopyTo(sw): for the 'sw' inside the parenthesis it gave me this error: Argument1: Conot convert from 'system.IO.StreamWriter TO System.IO.stream